# How to resize the content on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a canvas but when I resize the window, the canvas content is disappearing. I am using the following code. So the original size of canvas and background image is 960x558. And I am using those app.stage.canvas width and height because the canvas and background image is getting different on is resized.

```
function resize(){
        app.stage.canvas.width = $('#canvas').parent().width();
        //app.stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        app.stagetools.canvas.width = $('#canvas').parent().width();


        //tools container
        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 960){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '558';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 739){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '400';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 510){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '300';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 450){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '240';
            tools.toolsScale = 0.7;
        }

        tools.toolsContainer.scaleX = tools.toolsScale;
        tools.toolsContainer.scaleY = tools.toolsScale;
        tools.toolsContainer.x = app.stagetools.canvas.width/2 - 150 * tools.toolsScale;



        app.container.x = app.stage.canvas.width/2;
        app.container.y = app.stage.canvas.height/2;

        //background image      
        app.bgscale = app.stage.canvas.width /  app.backgroundBounds.width;

        if(app.backgroundBounds.height * app.bgscale > app.stage.canvas.height){
           app.bgscale = app.stage.canvas.height /  app.backgroundBounds.height;
        }

        app.backgroundContainer.scaleX = app.bgscale;
        app.backgroundContainer.scaleY = app.bgscale;


        app.backgroundContainer.x = Math.floor(app.stage.canvas.width/2 - app.backgroundBounds.width/2 * app.bgscale);
        app.backgroundContainer.y = Math.floor(app.stage.canvas.height/2 - app.backgroundBounds.height/2 * app.bgscale);


        tools.clearHandler();

        app.stage.update();
        app.stagetools.update();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is to be expected. When resizing the canvas its content is cleared.

From the **[standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#concept-canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions)**:

> When the user agent is to set bitmap dimensions to width and height,
>   it must run the following steps:
>       ...
>       3.  Resize the scratch bitmap to the new width and height and clear it to fully transparent black.
>       4. If the rendering context has an output bitmap, and the scratch bitmap is a different bitmap than the output bitmap, then resize the output bitmap to the new width and height and clear it to fully transparent black.

To get around this you must listen to the resize event of the window object and redraw all the content when invoked:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    // call redraw method here...
}, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and how it looks like this redraw method?

Comment: @zoolle that is up to you to define (whatever you need to redraw)