# How to scale canvas and keep the painted content without redraw?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, frontend

I have a canvas which is 800 * 400px used to do signature, and how can I resize the canvas and signature together?

ctx.scale method only resize the canvas but the painted content will disappear.

thx!

Comment: Maybe use zoom? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/ 
Can you add some example code to try it on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize a HTML 5 canvas and its content in pure Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882154/resize-a-html-5-canvas-and-its-content-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: Hello @monffy I believe you can find an answer on these pages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033116/resize-and-scale-html5-canvas-and-contents  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882154/resize-a-html-5-canvas-and-its-content-in-pure-javascript  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384013/how-to-resize-the-content-on-canvas